# Are orthogonal polynomials always generated by a 2nd order recurrence relation?

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Most of the orthogonal polynomials that we face, for example, in Physics are generated by recurrence relations of second order.

Are there examples of orthogonal polynomials generated by higher order recurrence relations? For example, the Chebyshev polynomials of second kind are generated by

$
U_{n}(x) = 2xU_{n-1}(x)-U_{n-2}(x)
$

with the initial conditions $U_0(x)=1$, $U_{-1}(x)=0$. If we modify this recurrence relation to,

$
V_{n}(x) = 2xV_{n-1}(x)-V_{n-3}(x)
$

with the initial conditions $V_0(x)=1$, $V_{-2}(x)=V_{-1}(x)=0$, how could I know if the family
$\{V_{n}(x)\}$ is orthogonal?

It is not clear to me whether Favard's theorem answers these questions.

Comment: A certain class of orthogonal polynomials always has this so-called "three term recurrence".  This will be explained in mathematics textbooks called "Orthogonal Polynomials".  Someone who knows more than I about this will have to answer to get more information than that.  See http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/ICM/LecturesAndSeminars/08OctMaterials/1/Slide2.pdf